# Particle に confusion in song lyrics 「ケーキに　クッキー　だいすき」

Tags: meaning, particle-に, song-lyrics

I was looking the lyrics of an opening song for Candy Candy (1976), and I couldn't understand that phrase:

> ケーキに　クッキー　だいすき

Other translations translate it something like "I love cakes and cookies" but I'm really confused because of the に-particle. Is it the correct translation or does it mean something else? How would you translate it?